# Why highcharts replaces symbol 9 by -

Tags: javascript, highcharts, vuejs2

For some reasons symbol `9` in labels of X axe looks like `-`.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/cknwyf6t/1/

Is there any methods to use normal symbol 9??

Comment: It displays perfectly right on my machine. Possibly some error in your font files. I have installed Lucida Sans Unicode on my machine, but not Lucida Grande

Comment: @yunzen, thanks a lot. I've reinstalled font and it's ok now.